# Android: random image with setImageResource from sequentially named resources

Tags: java, android, image, random, resources

I have a group of images in my resources.  For now Im working on a dice roller that will pick and display a random dice image 1-6.

Images named like so:  die1.png, die2.png, die3.png, die4.png, die5.png, die6.png

I seem to have stumbled upon a simple working method to do this, but to be honest I don't know if it's viable and stable because frankly I don't know how it works and would be keenly interested in being directed to any documentation or have someone explain WHY this works.  I don't want to be one of those guys that copy-pastes code and doesn't know why it works and I have spent quite some time trying to figure this one out and haven't come to a conclusion.

The code (in Eclipse if it matters):

```
    rand_1 = (int) Math.round(Math.random() * 5);
    dice1.setImageResource(R.drawable.die1 + rand_1);
```

So we get a number from 0 to 5 and add it to the resId of the first image in the naming sequence to randomly pull one of the 6 die images. Makes sense, but how can you be sure that the images in the resources folder are assigned resIDs sequentially like that?  For that matter, is there easy to understand documentation on how the compiler assigns the integer resource IDs?  I feel like I may be missing something simple here.  Thank you for your time guys and gals.

If this is not a stable solution (it seems to work fine once compiled so far) is there a better way to implement such behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Add this method to your class:

```
protected final static int getResourceID
(final String resName, final String resType, final Context ctx)
{
    final int ResourceID =
        ctx.getResources().getIdentifier(resName, resType,
            ctx.getApplicationInfo().packageName);
    if (ResourceID == 0)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException
        (
            "No resource string found with name " + resName
        );
    }
    else
    {
        return ResourceID;
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
rand_1 = (int) Math.round(Math.random() * 5);
dice1.setImageResource(getResourceID("die" + rand_1, "drawable", ctx));
```

Comment: Thank you for the information.  This method of finding the resource makes MUCH more sense to me than what was posted above, but the main reason I posted this question was to attempt to figure out why the solution I described in my OP works (and it does work as copied).  That said, this appears to be a very viable alternative and I thank you for providing it.